# Launch a UI component in jupyter notebook ISettingRegistry menu item click

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am trying to launch a UI component in Jupyter Notebook upon clicking an ISettingRegistry menu item, using a dialog. It works fine but due to the conflicting behaviour of the dialog(z-index, positions, and overlay) the text input fields are not focusable.

My code snippet below:

```
const myComponentWidget = new CreateClusterWidget(() => {
  // Callback function to close the dialog
  dialog.reject();
});
...
execute: () => {
  // open the widget
  dialog = new Dialog ({
    title: "Dialog Title",
    body: myComponentWidget,
    hasClose: true
  });
  dialog.launch();
}

Component:
import { ReactWidget } from "@jupyterlab/ui-components";
export class CreateClusterWidget extends ReactWidget {
  private closeDialogCallback: () => void;

  constructor(closeDialogCallback: () => void) {
    super();
    this.closeDialogCallback = closeDialogCallback;
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <CreateAttachCluster closeDialogCallback={this.closeDialogCallback} /> 
    );
  }
}
```

Is it possible to launch the component widget without using the dialog, which can show the component without affecting its behaviour?